# Backbone js filters display

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a collection of items with filters.  The filters are applied based on a few checkbox.  The collection of items changes if the users selects a different month (item are refreshed).

My approach is to loop over each item and then apply filters to the item if the item is a match show item else hide.  This approach works on the current month during load but when a another month is selected the loop is performed and if conditions that evaluate to false the condition is still executed.  I know the condition is false because when I place a break-point on the condition I am able to see within the console the statement evaluates to false.  Even when false the next step enters the condition.

Here is the code.

```
render: function() {
                display = this.model.get('display');
                filters = this.model.get('filters');


                //Check each class for filter parameters
                items.forEach(function (cla) {

                    //reset all items
                    $("#" + cla.id).parent().removeClass('matches');
                    $("#" + cla.id).parent().removeClass('noMatches');


                    //Get all filters
                    var hasCredit = "credits";
                    var hasLocation = "location";
                    var hasStarttime = "starttime";
                    var hasAreaOfStudy = "areaOfStudy";
                    var hasSpecialty = "specialty";
                    var hasEventCode = "eventcode";
                    var hasFormat = "format";
                    var itemFilters = [];

                    if (filters.inputs.length == 0) {
                        $("#" + cla.id).parent().addClass('matches');
                    } else {
                        //Loop over each filter
                        filters.inputs.forEach(function (el) {


                            //Check credit filter
                            if (el.name == 'credits') {
                                if (cla.credits.trim() == el.value) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasCredit);
                                }
                            } else if (el.name == 'specialty') {
                                if (jQuery.inArray(el.value.trim(), cla.specialty) !== -1) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasSpecialty);
                                }
                            } else if (el.name == 'areaOfStudy') {
                                if (jQuery.inArray(el.value, cla.areaOfStudy) !== -1) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasAreaOfStudy);
                                }

                            } else if (el.name == 'starttime') {
                                if (cla.starttime.trim() == el.value) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasStarttime);
                                }
                            } else if (el.name == 'location') {
                                if (cla.location.trim() == el.value) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasLocation);
                                }
                            } else if (el.name == 'eventcode') {
                                if (cla.id.trim() == el.value.trim()) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasEventCode);
                                }
                            } else if (el.name == 'format') {
                                if (cla.format == el.value) {
                                    itemFilters.push(hasFormat);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        var isInputFilterMatch = applyInputFilter(filters.inputs, itemFilters);

                        //All non matching filters get a noMatch css classed applied to be hidden
                        if (isInputFilterMatch) {
                            $("#" + cla.id).parent().addClass('matches');
                        } else {
                            $("#" + cla.id).parent().addClass('noMatches');
                        }
                    }

                });

                //Hide and show all matches and non matches
                $('.noMatches').hide();
                $('.matches').show();

                $('#main_main_MainContent_CpeCalendar').parent('.hidden-results').show();

                // shifted over to apply this after the items are set
                jQuery_1_4_2(".modal[href], .modal a[href]").colorbox();

                return this;    
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are better ways this could be implemented overall, but I'm going to take a stab at answering your question.

First, this code appears to be part of a View's render method. Since you haven't provided any additional code from your View, Collection, or Model, it leads me to ask, are you properly re-binding the view to the updated data in the collection? If not then based upon this snipped of code you provided I am thinking you might have to re-render the view to properly get all your data/event bindings to load on the collection data when it changes month-to-month since it might be getting lost:

```
$('#main_main_MainContent_CpeCalendar').parent('.hidden-results').show();

// shifted over to apply this after the items are set
jQuery_1_4_2(".modal[href], .modal a[href]").colorbox();

return this;
```

Instead of putting all of this inside of your View's `render()` method, whey don't you break this code up to make a bit more logical sense and to use the power that Backbone gives you? Here is an example of [filtering a Backbone Collection](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/filtering-a-collection-in-backbone-js/) using the Collection itself (which is a more suitable and maintainable approach).

Handle the filtering of a Backbone.Collection's items from within your Backbone.Collection itself and use its's handy connectivity to your database (which is acting as your sync between your View and Models which constitute the Collection) which is handy if the user initiates state changes via the UI to ensure data integrity instead of what you're doing here.

If you can provide the code from your Collection, Model, and View in whole, I might be able to provide you with a better answer to this question. Based on what I see here there are too many variables I don't know to resolve.